# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 'ALTER TABLE `field_revision_field_links` DISABLE KEYS */; INSERT INTO `field_rev' at line 5

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a import problem.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE `field_revision_field_links` DISABLE KEYS */;
>   INSERT INTO `field_rev' at line 5

This is a Drupal database. Can anyone help me? I exported the sql via putty and import the database via phpMyAdmin of Parallels Plesk. Thanks

More details:

1.) Server version 5.1.69-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 
2.) MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.69, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) 
3.) Drupal version 7.32

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `field_revision_field_links`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `field_revision_field_links` (
  `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
  `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to',
  `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
  `field_links_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_links_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`revision_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
  KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
  KEY `language` (`language`),
  KEY `field_links_format` (`field_links_format`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Revision archive storage for field 117 (field_links)';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `field_revision_field_links` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `field_revision_field_links` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `field_revision_field_links` VALUES ('node','basic_page',0,14,14,'und',0,'<a href=\"http://www.jcdecaux.co.uk/news\">News</a>','full_html'),('node','basic_page',0,14,14,'und',1,'http://www.jcdecaux.co.uk/','full_html');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `field_revision_field_links` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: care to post your query?

Comment: I've removed the Microsoft SQL Server tag since it's pretty obvious that you are using MySQL.

Comment: Are `;` at the end of the line neccesarry ? (after closing comment)

Comment: Actually I'm not that sure. I'm developing the back-end of the site, Once i upload it to our test server, it just appeared.

Comment: @jaczes Those are not comments. Those are valid statements that are only executed if the running version of MySQL is greater than the first number in those "comments".

Comment: @fancyPants, thanks for explanation :) Track was corrcect ;)

Comment: @bish already pull in the answer. Thanks to him. By deleting the semicolon after the valid statements (not comment). The problem is the different version from our local server to live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the whole comment line including the `;` after the comment,

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? Does this comments are necessary for Drupal imports?

Comment: The commands that are outcommented are dis/enabled keys. This is only needed when you import huge numbers of lines to speed up the import. The not commented `;` at the end of the line makes your syntax error.

Comment: Actually this is a huge import. 5512 lines to be exact.

Comment: Would not count this huge, but if you want you can uncomment the lines, so that they look like `ALTER TABLE `field_revision_field_links` DISABLE KEYS;` (make sure to have `ALTER` rights). But still the answer for your question of the syntax-error is the alone standing `;`at the end of the comment lines ;)

Comment: The error was gone. I just removed all semi-colons beside the comments (;). I don't know if this has a connection of the version of mysql in my local server and the version of mysql in the test server. but Thanks. :)